# Algorithm Ballots cast in an Election

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Can someone help me solve this?

We recently held an election for 3 positions.

There were 6 candidates.

Each member could cast 3 votes but could not vote for the same person more than once.

134 ballots were cast. (402 total votes)

The final tally was

```
result = {a:91, b:66, c:63, d:63, e:60, f:59}
```

I can easily determine the 20 possible unique ballots cast

```
result.keys.combination(3).to_a
```

But obviously given the number of possible combinations brute force would be impossibly time consuming so I am hoping someone can provide an algorithm to solve this practically.

I am trying to find a reasonably efficient way to determine a single possible tally of ballots but if you can provide multiple or all possible tallies that would be amazing.

Comment: Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody has more than one third of the possible votes, or if the number of votes is not a multiple of three, there is no possible answer.

If there are at least three votes left, and nobody has more than one third of the possible votes, decide on a ballot paper that gives the top three candidates one vote each and reduce their totals by one.

This process stops either with all votes accounted for or with somebody having more than one third of the vote. I think the worst case for this is votes (N+1, N, N, N) where you go to (N, N-1, N-1, N) where the count not decremented gains a little but does not reach one third, so I think you can continue this process to account for all votes cast.

There are obvious many different equivalent counts. Any pair of actions that do not overlap in two candidates has at least one possible alternative interpretation. One way to generate multiple solutions would be to chose possible ballots at random subject only to the constraint that no sum ever gets to more than one third of the possible votes left. Another would be to rearrange answers at random and follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm (although I have not proved that any particular set of small rearrangements makes the set of possible solutions connected)

Comment: Thank you I was just mentally stuck and this helped greatly. I will post a single search solution when I get a chance.

Answer (score 4):

Lets think about simpler thing, for example [canapé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canap%C3%A9). You have `N` small slices of bread and `M` ingredients (`Mi` pieces each).

You have to create `N` canapes with unique ingredients. Obviously, this is impossible if there is `Mi > N`.

> **reasonably efficient way to determine a *single* possible tally of ballots**

Arrange the bread slices in a line. Take the first ingredient and spread it all out, starting with the first slice of bread. Take the second ingredient and so on until you reach the last piece of bread. Return to the first slice of bread and continue to lay on top. Continue until you run out of ingredients.

```rb
require 'set'

result = {a: 91, b: 66, c: 63, d: 63, e: 60, f: 59} 
BALLOTS = 134
if (result.values.any? { |v| v > BALLOTS }) || (result.values.sum % BALLOTS != 0)
  raise 'Unfair election!'
end

ballots = BALLOTS.times.map { Set.new }
i = 0
result.each do |candidate, votes|
  votes.times do
    ballots[i % BALLOTS] << candidate
    i += 1
  end
end

puts "Do all of them have 3 unique votes? #{ballots.all? { |b| b.size == 3 }}"
```

Obviously, it's `O(∑Mi)` where `∑Mi` is 402 (your "total votes"). I don't think there is a faster way.

> **but if you can provide multiple or all possible tallies**

You can change the ingredients order. In your case there are `6! = 720` ways to fill the ballots. And I found that [60 of them are unique](https://pastebin.com/VNviKrdG).

There is different amount of unique tallies for the different results. There are only 10 unique ways for `result = {a: 67, b: 67, c: 67, d: 67, e: 67, f: 67}` for example.

Changing start position (`i = start # instead of 0`) does not provide new unique ways.

Comment: ..Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe I was so stuck on this but thank you @mcdowella for shaking me free of it.

We can just keep randomly shuffling and shifting the lists until we get a list where each group contains exactly 3 elements. It is definitely brute force but for a single result it is reasonably efficient (albeit unpredictable)

```
result = {a: 91, b: 66, c: 63, d: 63, e: 60, f: 59} 

votes = result.map { |candidate, count| [candidate] * count }

def build_election(arr)
  134.times.map do |x| 
    arr.shuffle.select {|a| !a.empty? }.first(3).map do |s| 
      s.pop
    end 
  end 
end
@a = build_election(votes.map(&:dup)) until @a&.all? {|s| s.size == 3}
```

Comment: I tried this with various values of `result` and it worked well. There in no certainty it will work, however. Suppose, for example, there were 3 candidates, A, B and C, each were to receive 2 votes and each ballot had 2 names. Suppose that initially, after randomizing, your arrays were `[['C','C'], ['A','A'], ['B','B']]`. You would then select `['C','A']` for the first ballot, leaving `[['C'], ['A'], ['B','B']]`. Next, after randomizing, suppose your arrays were `[['A'], ['C'], ['B','B']]`. You would then select `['A','C']` for the ballot, leaving `[[], [], ['B','B']]`...

Comment: ...At the next step you have a problem as you want to select one element from each of two arrays but there is only one non-empty array, namely `['B','B']`. This might be less of a problem if you were to sort the arrays by size--largest to smallest--at each step, but there still would be no assurance of finding a solution.

Comment: One possibility would be to add an outer loop that would "try again" if an answer were not found, up to some specified number of tries. Incidentally, if you were one of the candidates I would it assume it would have to be "e", in which case I wish you better luck next time.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I had thought about limiting the the loop and even using a `Set` to see how many hits I could get inside that limit. As to the results I was not running, although as a pure aside, I am currently in a legal battle involving certain unnamed state agencies against the aforementioned Association having held such election.

Comment: That sounds juicy. Let's hear about it on another Stack Exchange [site](https://law.stackexchange.com). One day I'd be most interested to hear how you found your way to Chester Springs...

Answer (score 1):

Although one can may be able to find a feasible solution for a given `result` using a heuristic algorithm, there is no assurance of that as it an NP-hard problem. It could be formulated as an integer linear program (ILP). In principle, ILP software will identify a feasible solution or report that no feasible solution exists. I say "in principle" because the problem may well be unsolvable in the time available.

This ILP problem has 20x6 = 120 non-negative, integer-valued variables and 6 constraints.

The variables are:

n<sub>i</sub>   : the number of times ballot i is cast, i = 1,2,...,20

`#<Set: {1, 3, 5}>` is an example of one of the 20 ballots.

There are two types of known constants:

a<sub>ij</sub>  : equal to 1 if ballot i contains a vote for candidate j,
i = 1,2,...,20, j = 1,...,6, else zero

v<sub>j</sub>   : the number of votes candidate j is to receive, j = 1,...,6

The constraints are as follows.

∑<sub>i</sub>n<sub>i</sub>a<sub>ij</sub> =  v<sub>j</sub>, j = 1,...,6

n<sub>i</sub> >= 0 and integer-valued, i = 1,2,...,20

The first set of contraints ensures that each candidate receives the specified number of votes. The second set of contraints is implicit in ILP's.

ILP's also have objective functions to be maximized or minimimized, subject to the constraints. Here only a feasible solution is desired so the objective function might be expressed as

max 0x<sub>1</sub>

or something equivalent.

Comment: Welcome. I assumed you'd make it here sooner or later with a well thought out explanation to the problem. Thanks for taking a look but I am sure you can come up with some kind of solution and likely to be more elegant than my shotgun on a merry-go-round approach.