# Ruby. Shuffle the array so that there are no adjacent elements with the same value

Tags: ruby, algorithm

An array of hashes is given (10 elements at least):

```
arr = [{letter: "a", number: "1"}, {letter: "a", number: "3"}, {letter: "b", number: "4"}, {letter: "b", number: "1"}, ..., {letter: "e", number: "2"} ]
```

The task is to shuffle the array so that there are no adjacent elements with the same 'letter' value.

So, the result should be like the following:

```
[{letter: "c", number: "4"}, {letter: "a", number: "1"}, {letter: "e", number: "2"}, {letter: "b", number: "1"}, ..., {letter: "a", number: "3"} ]
```

What is the simplest way to do that?

**=== UPDATE ===**

The number of repeated letters in the array is precisely known - it's 20% of the array length.
So, the array looks like the following:

```
[
{letter: "a", number: "1"}, {letter: "a", number: "3"}, 
{letter: "b", number: "4"}, {letter: "b", number: "1"},
{letter: "c", number: "7"}, {letter: "c", number: "3"},
{letter: "d", number: "6"}, {letter: "d", number: "4"},
{letter: "e", number: "5"}, {letter: "e", number: "2"}
]
```

Or, its simplified version:

```
["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e"]
```

Or, for example, there is a simplified array containing 15 elements:

```
["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e"]
```

Comment: It might simply be impossible. What about `aaab`?

Comment: What I would do is first group the array members by their "letter" value and the iteratively extract a member of a random group that is _not_ the same as the previous group (adding this extracted member to the result array).

Comment: I know how to do this.  But it is complicated and it uses a bunch of techniques that I've never seen anyone other than me use.

Comment: @maxpleaner That approach will lead to a sampling that is biased towards some orderings and not others.

Comment: Do you want an approximate answer, or a perfect one?  An approximate answer will be much simpler while having modest bias (some shuffles will be more likely than others).  A perfect answer that makes all shuffles equally likely is possible but will require a lot of work.

Comment: @btilly the perfect answer has nothing to do with bias, distribution, or technique, since the only question that was asked is *"What is the simplest way to do that?"*

Comment: @btilly can you explain why my suggested approach would bias the ordering?

Comment: I'm confident--and expect it's been proven--that an equivalent problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness): given a collection of objects, find an ordering such that no pair of consecutive objects have a given property (such as being in some sense equal). Can you tell use why you wish to find such an ordering? Perhaps there is a more workable alternative.

Comment: @CarySwoveland this sounds very much like an interview or homework question.

Comment: @maxpleaner Take the simple case of 3 `a`s, 2 `b`s and 1 `c`.  Let's ignore the value part of it.  There are 10 answers, 10 of which start with `a` and 2 for `b` and 1 for `c`.  The second letter is `b` half the time though.  Make those frequencies 4, 3, and 2 and there are now 79 solutions with `a` starting 45 times, `b` starting 21 and `c` starting 13.  `b` is the second letter now about 40% of the time.  If you're picking one letter at a time, unless you can figure out those statistics, the solutions won't have those exact proportions.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't think it is NP-complete.  For `n` objects I have a dynamic programming solution over the partitions of `n`, which is exponential in `sqrt(n)`.  If that could solve an NP-complete problem, I think that you'd demonstrate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis to be false, which would be pretty big news.

Comment: @engineersmnky The simplest way to provide an exact answer is simply to generate random shuffles until one works out.  It might run painfully slowly, but it is very simple.  The simplest way to provide an exact answer with bounded running time that I can think of is very complicated.  The simplest way to provide an approximate answer is not so complicated.  That is why knowing how good an answer matters.

Comment: @btilly simple and good are inexactitudes. There can be no exact answer to what is good, or simple, since those statements are derivatives of a personal perspective. Since the question did not specify any bounds and given the potentially small set size defined (`n > 10`) your exactness could potentially drastically underperform regardless of a bounding time due to its eluded complexity, if a solution is even possible which is an assumption of the conditions given.

Comment: @engineersmnky I assure you that I am well aware of all of that and more.  As I like to put it, "Scalability is like a Mack truck, great when you need it but not always the best thing to use for carrying your groceries."  But repeat yourself as often as you like.  Some drive by reader might wind up enlightened.

Comment: @btilly, you are correct, it is not NP-complete. In fact, as I show in my answer, a solution can be readily obtained for even large arrays. I do not see how it can be solved with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation), however. Perhaps you could outline the sequence of operations that would be performed.

Comment: When you give an example it's best for inputs and the desired result to be valid Ruby objects (here avoid `...,`), so that answers can demonstrate that suggested code produces the desired result for the example.

Comment: @engineersmnky This problem is a special case of your ballot question.

Comment: Please do not change--as opposed to clarify--the question after an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple and maybe the less effective way could be the brute force.

So on a simplified version of the array, one can do:

```
ary = %w(a a c c b a s)

loop do
  break if ary.shuffle!.slice_when { |a, b| a == b }.to_a.size == 1
end
```

Some check should be added to assure that a solution exists, to avoid infinite loop.

---

Other (better?) way is to shuffle then find the permutation (no infinite loop) which satisfy the condition:

```
ary.shuffle!    
ary.permutation.find { |a| a.slice_when { |a, b| a == b }.to_a.size == 1 }
```

If a solution does not exist, it returns `nil`.

---

Run the the benchmark:

```
def looping
  ary = %w(a a c c b a s)
  loop do
    break if ary.shuffle!.slice_when { |a, b| a == b }.to_a.size == 1
  end
  ary
end

def shuffle_permute
  ary = %w(a a c c b a s)
  ary.shuffle!
  ary.permutation.lazy.find { |a| a.slice_when { |a, b| a == b }.to_a.size == 1 }
end

require 'benchmark'

n = 500
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { looping }
  x.report { shuffle_permute }
end
```

Comment: Another brute-force approach is to generate all permutations, reject those with identical adjacent elements, and take one sample. It's probably much slower but on the other side more deterministic.

Comment: You are correct, @Stefan: actually I considered `ary.permutation.select { |a| a.slice_when { |a, b| a == b }.to_a.size == 1 }.sample(1).flatten` but it performed two orders of magnitude slower than the others, so I dropped it.

Comment: @iGian The second solution gives me adjacent letters: [link](https://take.ms/NWd05)

Comment: @Ivan, my code works on the [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) array of my example. You have an array of hashes, so you need to access the objects and compare the value at key ':letter': `a[:letter] == b[:letter]`. The same applies to the first method (which seems to be faster on larger arrays).

Comment: `arr.permutation.find { |a| a.slice_when { |a, b| a[:letter] == b[:letter] }.to_a.size == 1 }` this solutions works, but it takes about 30 seconds in my IRB to give results (for an array consisting of 15 elements only)... that's too long :(

Comment: And the first solution with `loop` always gives me `nil`: [link](https://take.ms/QhnAH)

Comment: "The simple and maybe the less effective way could be the brute force." - "`a[:letter] == b[:letter]`. The same applies to the first method".

Comment: A variant to #1 is `a = loop { arr = arr.shuffle; break arr if arr.each_cons(2).all? { |g,h| g[:letter] != h[:letter] } }. For `arr` in my answer that returns `[{:letter=>"f"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"a"}]`.

Comment: Thank you, guys.

Comment: Another note `break` can return so looping can be `break ary if #...` and you can remove the trailing `ary`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way (without any random):

```rb
# Calculate letter frequency
freq = arr.group_by { |h| h[:letter] }.map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }.to_h

# Then check that the most frequent element occurs less that arr.size / 2
center = (arr.size + 1) / 2
if freq.values.max > center
  # Impossible
end

# Sort array by frequency to have most frequent first.
sarr = arr.sort_by { |h| freq[h[:letter]] }.reverse

sarr[0..center-1].zip(sarr[center..-1]).flatten.compact
```

Your problem is a special case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64180561/8098012). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628113/8098012) for the detailed explanation how this works.

---

We even don't need to sort by letter frequency. It's for corner cases like "abbcccc". We can solve them in another way:

```rb
# Works with correct data: most frequent letter occurs <= center times
def f(arr)
  arr = arr.sort
  center = (arr.size + 1) / 2
  arr = arr[0..center-1].zip(arr[center..-1]).flatten.compact
  double = (1..arr.size-1).find { |i| arr[i] == arr[i-1] }
  double ? arr.rotate(double) : arr # fix for the corner cases
end

puts f(%w[a a a a b b c].shuffle).join
# ababaca
puts f(%w[a a b b b b c].shuffle).join
# bcbabab
puts f(%w[a b b c c c c].shuffle).join
# cacbcbc
```

The only non-linear part of the algorithm is `arr.sort`. But as you can see by the link above, we even don't need the sorting. We need letters counts, which could be found in linear time. Therefore, we can reduce the algorithm to `O(n)`.

---

> The number of repeated letters in the array is precisely known - it's 20% of the array length.

With this update, the algorithm is simplified to (as there are no corner cases):

```rb
sarr = arr.sort_by { |h| h[:letter] }
center = (arr.size + 1) / 2
sarr[0..center-1].zip(sarr[center..-1]).flatten.compact
```

Comment: The frequency of letters is equal and the array structure is precisely known (see the 'update' part in the description). What would be your solution in this case?

Comment: Very nice, Pavel! Your #2 needs a wee tweak: `f ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'] #=> ["a", "a", "b", "a"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `f(arr)` is for valid arrays only. The goal was to demonstrate a deterministic algorithm with O(n logn) / O(n) for correct input.

Comment: @CarySwoveland BTW, you could review the links from the answer, as you also took part in discussing that "ballots" problem.

Comment: @Ivan It's pretty easy, updated the answer.

Comment: I was merely suggesting that you add the check `if freq.values.max > center -> impossible` in #1 to #2.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk My test in IRB showed me two adjacent 'c' letters: [link](https://take.ms/K9gPU)

Comment: @Ivan Nobody noticed that the center was calculated incorrectly :) Fixed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I got it, but I wanted to keep #2 code as short as possible. Also I didn't calculate the frequency in #2 (so couldn't just copy the check). I think the shortest way is to check the final result on doubles :)

Comment: `sarr[0..center-1]` could be expressed as `sarr[0...center]` or even `sarr.partition.with_index {|_,i| i < center}.reduce(&:zip).flatten`

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
def reorder(arr)
  groups = arr.group_by { |h| h[:letter] }
  return nil if 2 * groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max > arr.size + 1
  max_key = groups.max_by { |_,a| a.size }.first
  letters = ([max_key] + (groups.keys - [max_key])).cycle
  ordered = []
  while ordered.size < arr.size
    k = letters.next
    ordered << groups[k].pop unless groups[k].empty?
  end
  ordered
end
```

`nil`is returned if it is not possible to rearrange the elements in such a way that `g[:letter] != h[:letter]` for all pairs of consecutive elements `g` and `h`.

Note that this method has near linear computational complexity, `O(arr.size)`, "near" because hash lookups are not quite constant time.

If desired, one could call the method with `arr` randomized: `reorder(arr.shuffle)`.

**Example**

```
arr = [
  { letter: "a" }, { letter: "e" }, { letter: "b" }, { letter: "b" },
  { letter: "e" }, { letter: "a" }, { letter: "a" }, { letter: "f" } 
]
```

```
reorder(arr)
  #=> [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"},
  #    {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"a"}]
```

**Proof**

The assertion is that if the line

```
return nil if 2 * groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max > arr.size + 1
```

were removed from the method the array returned by the method would have the property that for all pairs of successive elements, `g`, `h`, `g[:letter]` != `h[:letter]` if and only if

```
2 * groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max <= arr.size + 1
```

The proof has two parts.

*The above inequality holds if the method produces a valid array*

Compute

```
max_key = groups.max_by { |_,a| a.size }.first
max_key_freq = groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max
```

and assume a valid array is returned. There must be at least one element other than `max_key` between each successive value of `max_key` in that array. The number of elements of `arr` other than `max_key` must therefore be at least `max_key_freq - 1`, so that

```
max_key_freq + max_key_freq - 1 <= arr.size
```

Hence,

```
2 * max_key_freq <= arr.size + 1
```

which is the same as:

```
2 * groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max <= arr.size + 1
```

*The above inequality does not hold if the method produces an invalid array*

Suppose `ordered` is returned and it contains successive elements `g` and `h` for which both `g[:letter]` and `h[:letter]` equal the same letter `l`.

Because of the way `ordered` is constructed:

- `groups[k]` must be empty for all keys `k` in `groups` for which `k != l`;
- `f[:letter]` must equal `l` for all elements of `ordered` following `g` (if there are any); and
- `l` must be the first key enumerated by `keys`, which is a letter that appears with a frequency that is not less than that of any other letter. `l` has frequency `groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max`.

If `n = groups.keys.size` there must be a non-negative integer `k` (loosely, the number of *rounds* of allocations for all keys of `groups`) such that the number of elements `h` of `arr` for which `h[:letter] != l` equals `k*n` and the number of elements `h` of `arr` for which `h[:letter] == l` is `k*n + 2 + m`, where `m >= 0`. The size of `arr` is therefore `2*k*n + 2 + m`.

In that case,

```
2 * groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max > arr.size + 1
-> 2 * (k*n + 2 + m) > (k*n + 2 + m + k*n) + 1
-> 2*k*n + 4 + 2*m > 2*k*n + 3 + m
-> (4-3) + m > 0
-> true
```

**Explanation**

For the example,

```
groups = arr.group_by { |h| h[:letter] }
  #=> {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}],
  #    "e"=>[{:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"e"}],
  #    "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"b"}],
  #    "f"=>[{:letter=>"f"}]}
```

The following tells us that a solution exists.

```
2 * groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max > arr.size + 1
  #=> 2 * [3, 2, 2, 1].max > 8 + 1
  #=> 2 * 3 > 9
  #=> 6 > 9
  #=> false
```

Next create an enumerator `letters`.

```
  max_key = groups.max_by { |_,a| a.size }.first
    #=> "a"
  letters = ([max_key] + (groups.keys - [max_key])).cycle
    #=> #<Enumerator: ["a", "e", "b", "f"]:cycle>
```

The elements of `letters` are generated as follows.

```
letters.next #=> "a"
letters.next #=> "e"
letters.next #=> "b"
letters.next #=> "f"
letters.next #=> "a"
letters.next #=> "e"
... ad infinititum
```

See [Array#cycle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle).

I can best explain the remaining calculations by salting the method with `puts` statements before running the method. Note that `arr.size #=> 8`.

```
def reorder(arr)
  groups = arr.group_by { |h| h[:letter] }
  puts "groups = #{groups}"
  return nil if 2 * groups.map { |_,v| v.size }.max > arr.size + 1
  max_key = groups.max_by { |_,a| a.size }.first
  letters = ([max_key] + (groups.keys - [max_key])).cycle
  ordered = []
  while ordered.size < arr.size
    puts "\nordered.size = #{ordered.size} < #{arr.size} = #{ordered.size < arr.size}" 
    k = letters.next
    puts "k = #{k}"
    puts "groups[#{k}].empty? = #{groups[k].empty?}"
    ordered << groups[k].pop unless groups[k].empty?
    puts "ordered = #{ordered}"
    puts "groups = #{groups}"
  end
  ordered
end
```

```
reorder(arr)
  #=> [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"},
  #    {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"a"}]
```

The following is displayed.

```
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}],
          "e"=>[{:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"e"}],
          "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"b"}],
          "f"=>[{:letter=>"f"}]}
```

```
ordered.size = 0 < 8 = true
k = a
groups[a].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}],
          "e"=>[{:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"e"}],
          "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"b"}],
          "f"=>[{:letter=>"f"}]}
```

```
ordered.size = 1 < 8 = true
k = e
groups[e].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}],
          "e"=>[{:letter=>"e"}],
          "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"b"}],
          "f"=>[{:letter=>"f"}]}
```

```
ordered.size = 2 < 8 = true
k = b
groups[b].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}],
          "e"=>[{:letter=>"e"}],
          "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}],
          "f"=>[{:letter=>"f"}]}
```

```
ordered.size = 3 < 8 = true
k = f
groups[f].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"a"}],
          "e"=>[{:letter=>"e"}], "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}],
          "f"=>[]}
```

```
ordered.size = 4 < 8 = true
k = a
groups[a].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"},
           {:letter=>"a"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}],
          "e"=>[{:letter=>"e"}],
          "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}],
          "f"=>[]}
```

```
ordered.size = 5 < 8 = true
k = e
groups[e].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"},
           {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}],
          "e"=>[],
          "b"=>[{:letter=>"b"}],
          "f"=>[]}
```

```
ordered.size = 6 < 8 = true
k = b
groups[b].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"},
           {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}], "e"=>[], "b"=>[], "f"=>[]}
```

```
ordered.size = 7 < 8 = true
k = f
groups[f].empty? = true
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"},
           {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}]
groups = {"a"=>[{:letter=>"a"}], "e"=>[], "b"=>[], "f"=>[]}
```

```
ordered.size = 7 < 8 = true
k = a
groups[a].empty? = false
ordered = [{:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"f"},
           {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"a"}]
groups = {"a"=>[], "e"=>[], "b"=>[], "f"=>[]}
```

---

---

Refering to the revised question, if

```
arr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e"]
```

one could simply write:

```
arr.each_slice(arr.index { |s| s != arr.first }.to_a.transpose.flatten
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

or

```
arr.each_slice(arr.count(arr.first)).to_a.transpose.flatten
```

Comment: `arr.group_by { |h| h[:letter] }.values.sort_by {|a| -a.size}.then {|max,*rest| max.zip(*rest) }.flatten.compact` seem like it would produce the same result. Likely less efficient (a lot of intermediaries) but points for one breath :)

Comment: @engineersmnky, I had something close to that at some point but made the change to go from O(nlog(n)) to (close to) O(n). Obsessive? Perhaps.

Comment: This solution gives a kind of intended result, but it lacks variety. It always gives the same order, like `[aabbccddee]` -> `[abcdeabcde]`. I'm looking for a solution where the letters would be placed randomly every time.

Comment: You could call the method `reorder(arr.shuffle)` but that will still not yield a random reordering amongst all valid reorderings. All I can suggest is to call the method `arr.shuffle` repeatedly until a valid  rearrangement is obtained. Depending on the array, however, that could take a very long time. You'd want to first test that a solution exists, as I did.  Contructing a (conceptually) truly random sample for this problem is a difficult statistical problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The solution exists, I know it for sure (look at the update in the description).
However, how can I check if the valid rearrangement is obtained by using `arr.shuffle`? What will be the code?

Comment: One way: `loop { arr = arr.shuffle; break if arr.each_cons(2).all? { |g,h| g[:letter] != h[:letter] } }`, then `arr` will have the desired property. See [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) and [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Comment: Suppose `arr` contained `n` `1`'s and `n` `2`'s and nothing else. Then there will be two "successful" outcomes of `arr.shuffle` that will have the desire property:  `[1,2,1,2,...,1,2]` and `[2,1,2,1,...,2,1]`. The number of possible `arr.shuffle` outcomes is `n = (2*n)!/(n!*n!)`, so the probability that `arr.shuffle` will result in one of the two successful outcomes (a sucess) is `2/n` and the average number of applications of `shuffle` required to achieve a success will be `n/2`...

Comment: ...For `n = 5` the probability that each application of `arr.shuffle` results in a success is `0.0079` and, on average, a success would occur after `126.0` applications of `arr = arr.shuffle`.  For `n = 10` those values are `1.0825e-05` and `92378.0`; for `n= 50` they are `1.9823e-29` and `5.0446e+28`.

Comment: `loop { arr = arr.shuffle; break if arr.each_cons(2).all? { |g,h| g[:letter] != h[:letter] } }` - this gives me `nil`: [link](https://take.ms/vQlu9)

Comment: Sorry. `a = loop { arr = arr.shuffle; break arr if arr.each_cons(2).all? { |g,h| g[:letter] != h[:letter] } } #=> [{:letter=>"f"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"b"}, {:letter=>"a"}, {:letter=>"e"}, {:letter=>"a"}]`for `arr` as defined at the beginning of my answer. Notice that I changed `break` to `break arr` and `arr` is not mutated.

Comment: Thank you, @CarySwoveland. That's exactly what's needed. Could you please add this solution to your answer?

Comment: I added a comment to @iGian's answer, as my suggestion is just a variant of the first part of his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like backtracking.

I would build the "shuffled" array from left to right.

Assume that there are N elements in the array. Say that at some point during the algorithm, you have already the first k elements arranged to fulfil the condition.

Now you pick from the remaining (N-k) elements the first one, which you can append to your result array, without breaking the condition.

If you can find one, you repeat the process recursively, now having an result array of (k+1) elements.

If you can not find one, you return a failure indicator and let the caller (i.e. the previous recursion) try another choice.